# Smart contract break for loop in smartpy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I need to break a for loop in smartpy, but `break` does not work.
Is there any other solution I could use?

Answer (score 2):

Michelson is a functional language. `break statements` have no (clean) sense.

[LOOP_LEFT](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-LOOP_LEFT) is an approximation for `break statements`, but in smartpy you can do the following:

```
import smartpy as sp

class MyContract(sp.Contract):
  def __init__(self, **kargs):
    self.init(**kargs)

  @sp.entry_point
  def ep(self):
    stop = sp.local("stop", False)
    sp.while ~ stop.value:
      sp.if self.data.value > 5:
        stop.value = True
      sp.else:
        self.data.value += 1
        
    
@sp.add_test(name = "Example")
def test():
  scenario = sp.test_scenario()
  c1 = MyContract(value = 0)
  scenario += c1
  c1.ep()
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I am trying to cut the keys list of a map into chunks (first 50 entries, then next fifty entries, till the end). That's why I needed a break statement. Unfortunately a while loop won't help me since I need to iterate through my keys list. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: That is not supported in Michelson, the instruction is https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-ITER, and it iterates over all elements. You can have an IF that ignores elements when some condition is met.

Comment: You could first filter the lists of keys, splitting the keys into multiple lists depending on what you are trying to do and then iterate over all of them.